# Can I configure Prettier to format my React file such that all useStates are clustered at top?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using **VSCode** and my `prettier.config.js` looks like this below:

```
// prettier.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("prettier-plugin-tailwindcss")],
  printWidth: 80,
  tabWidth: 4,
  trailingComma: "all",
  singleQuote: true,
  semi: true,
  importOrder: ["^@core/(.*)$", "^@server/(.*)$", "^@ui/(.*)$", "^[./]"],
  importOrderSeparation: true,
  importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
};
```

Here is how my component looks like. If you see, there is a `useState` in the middle that should ideally be reformatted to be at the top, where all other `useState` are.  I don't know if there a config that also takes care of the organisation of not just `useState` but other things like `useRouter` to appear at the very top too. Meanwhile, I want the `useEffect` to be at the bottom just before the `return`. I suffer from OCD and this ordering matters to me a lot.

```
...
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';

function ItemLinkScreen(props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { 'space-slug': spaceSlug, 'section-slug': sectionSlug } = router.query;

    const { mutate } = useSpace(spaceSlug);

    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
    const [framelyResponse, setFramelyResponse] = useState(null);
    const [framelyError, setFramelyError] = useState(null);
    const [dialogOpened, setDialogOpened] = useState(false);

    const schema = yup.object({
        name: yup.string().min(3).max(255).required(),
    });

    const {
        register,
        reset,
        formState: { errors },
        setFocus,
        handleSubmit,
        control,
    } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });
    const [apiErrors, setApiErrors] = useState([]);

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setFocus('name');
    }, [dialogOpened]);

   

    return (
        
    );
}

export default ItemLinkScreen;
```